# UpdateIf removing focus of item in PowerApps Gallery

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am currently troubleshooting a PowerApp made by a different company where tabbing between fields is not working as expected.

I discovered within a gallery containing text boxes that the "OnChange" properties of these items of a "UpdateIf" function inside them, which appears to be causing the form to lose focus on the item selected.

I was trying to do something like a SetFocus on the item, but that apparently is not supported within the gallery.

I am open to any suggestions including maybe a different best practice to achieve the same sort of result, if there is anything I can do to clarify please ask.

Answer (score -1):

You can make colour change as selected items to show focus.

Thisitem.selected may work

To display focus

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).